# How to pull and display parent div

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I'm a jQuery noob. I'd like to iterate through a list of html classes and for each class display the name of the parent div. Specifically, I'd like to iterate through the food_type classes below and display the parent id for each (e.g., 'chicken'). So something like this...

```
$(".food_type").each(function() {
      alert(...)


  <div id="chicken">
      <div class="kg"></div>
      <div class="food_type">100</div>
      <div class="label">Chicken</div>
  </div>

 <div id="eggs">
    <div class="kg"></div>
    <div class="food_type">100</div>
    <div class="label">Eggs</div>
  </div>

  <div id="pork">
    <div class="kg"></div>
    <div class="food_type">100</div>
    <div class="label">Pork</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the `each` method, `this` keyword regards to the element being iterated through. So you wrap it into a jQuery object (by doing `$(this)` ) and get its `parent`. Finally, you get the parent's `id` attribute. Put it all together and you have this:

```
$(".food_type").each(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
}
```

Further reading:

- http://api.jquery.com/each/
- http://api.jquery.com/parent/
- http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".food_type").each(function() {
  alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".food_type").each(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().prop("id"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$(".food_type").each(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().attr("id"));
}
```

`parent()` gets the element's parent, and `attr("id")` gets the element's ID. `each` just iterates through the array generated by `$(".food_type")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".food_type").each(function() {
      var category = $(this).parent().attr('id');
});
```